# Visual Studio Configure Data Source MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, database-connection, datasource

Okay well I have been accessing a mysql database in my website. I am able to connect perfectly and insert and select things from the database.

```
server = "localhost";
        database = "datamain";
        uid = "root";
        password = "fakepassword";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
     database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

now I am wanting to put in a listview. I then go to choose new datasource. Then I put in all my data and test connection it works, so I click okay. And now I am done so I click finish. Then it says:

```
The data provider "MySQL.data.MySQLClient could not be found in the system configuration. Unable to find the requested .NET framework Data provider. It may not be installed
```

And yes I have the references in bin, because it is letting me connect manually to the database

UPDATE: I can even manually get a datasource

```
 try
    {
        String sCon = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=datamain;UID=root;PASSWORD=fakepassword";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sCon);
        String s = "Select * from tb_login";
        MySqlDataAdapter dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dat.Fill(ds, "tb_login");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
```

And my web.config look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes ill find that. Also I found out I could manually connect. I updated my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to fix it. What I did is I went to mysql re-downloaded the connector, and then restarted visual studio. Then when I tried making a datasource again it worked.